# Python Socket server-cliente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando crear un **socket** para comunicar un **cliente** con el **servidor**.

El **server** debe estar siempre activo esperando conexiones en el puerto que le indico. Una vez establecida la conexión con ese puerto no debe detenerse hasta que el cliente no se desconecte.

El **cliente**, por su parte, envía constantemente strings por el socket que el server debe recibir.

Este es el código de mi **servidor**:

```
import re, socket
from time import sleep
local, port = ('0.0.0.0'), 1010

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((local, port))
server.listen(1)
print("Server started")

clientConnection,clientAddress = server.accept()

while True:
    
    print ("CONNECTED CLIENT: ", clientAddress)
    recv = clientConnection.recv(4096)

    print ("RECIEVED STRING: "+recv.decode())
    clientConnection.sendall(bytes("hola",'utf-8'))
```

El `while` lo uso para que imprima todos los mensajes que va recibiendo, ya que sin un bucle solo me imprimía el primero y se cerraba la comunicación.

El lado del **cliente**:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

i = 5
n = 1

while n < i:

    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect(('1.1.1.1',1010)
    
    msg = "test"
    my_socket.send(msg.encode())
    
    data = my_socket.recv(4096)
    print (data)
    n = n+1
```

Mi problema llega cuando al intentar enviar varios mensajes des de el cliente al servidor, por eso el bucle, solo me llega el primero. Output del lado del servidor:

```
Server started
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: test
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: 
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: 
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: 
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING:
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\SOCKET\testConn.py", line 15, in <module>
    recv = clientConnection.recv(4096)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host
```

Lo que me gustaría es recibir todos los mensajes que envía el cliente.

```
Server started
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: test
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: test
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: test
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: test
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('1.1.1.1', 24879)
RECIEVED STRING: test
```

A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano con esto. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu cliente, una vez ha emitido un número de mensajes "test", termina su ejecución. La terminación del cliente causa el cierre del canal TCP y por tanto en el lado servidor por ese canal ya nunca llegará nada más (el hecho de que te lleguen cadenas vacías es la forma que tiene el socket de señalar que el canal está cerrado). Tampoco podrás enviar nada más por ese socket y esa es la razón por la que al final acabas obteniendo el error `ConnectionAbortedError`

Si lanzas clientes adicionales, cada uno será una conexión nueva (y por tanto un canal nuevo). Aunque al lanzar un cliente adicional aparentemente se "conecte" con el servidor, con quien conecta en realidad es con el sistema operativo de la máquina donde está el servidor. El servidor en sí es desconocedor de esas conexiones hasta que no haga de nuevo `accept()`, cosa que no hará nunca porque está atrapado en un bucle infinito tratando de leer de un socket que ya no es válido porque el canal fue cerrado.

En definitiva tienes que modificar el servidor para que detecte el cierre de la conexión (cuando `recv()` devuelva cadena vacía) y en ese caso deje de intentar leer de ese socket y pase a hacer otra vez `accept()` sobre el socket de escucha, para crear nuevas conexiones con otros clientes.

El servidor quedaría por tanto así:

```
import re, socket
from time import sleep

local, port = ('0.0.0.0'), 1010

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((local, port))
server.listen(1)
print("Server started")

while True:                 # Bucle para esperar clientes nuevos
    clientConnection,clientAddress = server.accept()
    print ("CONNECTED CLIENT: ", clientAddress)

    while True:             # Bucle para repetir con un cliente conectado
        recv = clientConnection.recv(4096)
        if recv == b"":     # Recibida cadena de bytes vacía implica desconexión
            break           # Salir de este bucle interno

        print ("RECIEVED STRING: "+recv.decode())
        clientConnection.sendall(bytes("hola",'utf-8'))
    
    print("CLIENT DISCONNECTED")
    clientConnection.close()   # Cerramos el socket pues ya no es útil
    # Y volvemos a aceptar otro cliente
```

Comment: Veo un problema con el break del segundo bucle, al recibir una string vacía cerrará la comunicación del socket, cosa que no debería ocurrir. Me gustaría que se quede a la espera.

Comment: Entiendo tu inquietud, pero no puedes recibir una string vacía, porque de hecho no puedes enviar una string vacia. Si intentas un `sendall(bytes(""))`  en el lado cliente, realmente esa instrucción no hará nada y el correspondiente `recv()` del servidor seguirá esperando. La única forma en que `recv()` te puede devolver una string vacía es que la conexión esté cortada.

Comment: Lo más parecido a una string vacía que puedes enviar es una que contenga simplemente un retorno de carro (pero entonces no estará vacía, y será diferente de `b""` en el lado servidor)

Comment: En el momento en el que yo detengo el enviamiento de datos desde el cliente(cierro socket), no habría manera de que el server siga esperando nuevas  conexiones, sin yo tener que ejecutarlo cada vez?

Comment: En mi código eso es lo que debería ocurrir (y de hecho ocurre, lo he probado). Cuando cierras el cliente el servidor abandona el  `while` interno, pero sigue dentro del `while True` principal, por lo que volverá a la línea que contiene el `accept()`, donde quedará a la espera de un nuevo cliente.

Comment: Normalmente queda más claro si se pone un `if not recv: break`. También recomendaría usar bloques `with` para agrupar las sentencias que usan una misma conexión.

Comment: @abulafia lo he estado mirando y lo que me ocurre es que al cerrar la conexion desde el cliente en el servidor me muestra el siguiente mensaje y se cierra; `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto`

Comment: Eso es porque en el lado servidor no has detectado correctamente el cierre del socket, o porque intentas escribirle una respuesta "hola" después de que el socket ha sido cerrado. Si detectas que `recv` es la cadena vacía, entonces no debes enviar nunca nada más por ese socket, sino cerrarlo y volver a la espera de accept